# Creating a valid filename with dir and fullfile

Tags: matlab, file-io

I keep running across this error in my code:

```
Path = 'C:\Users\18606\OneDrive\Documents\Spheroids For Brandon\Spheroids\1-8WT';
Content = dir(Path); 
SubFold = Content([Content.isdir]); % Keep only the directories
MyData = []; 
for k = 3:length(SubFold)
    F = fullfile(Path, SubFold(k).name);
    fileID = fopen(F);
    MyData{end+1} = fopen(fileID,'%s\n');
    fclose(fileID);
```

Resulting in the error:

```
Error using fopen
Invalid filename (line 8)
```

The code is trying to iterate over multiple images in multiple subfolders of the main. The goal is to process the images with an edge detection algorithm for each file, but that's besides the point. Why would the program give an invalid file name when the path, content and subfolders are all specified in the code? Do the variables mentioned have anything to do with the error? Finally, is there a better way to open and read the images iteratively?

Comment: Please do not change the question significantly after you've received answers. If you'd like to answer your own question, please do so, [it's even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you'd like to ask a new question instead, please ask a separate one ("Why doesn't `fopen(file.tiff)` work?" or similar). I've rolled back the edit for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading in files sequentially is indeed usually done through looping over a `dir()` call, i.e. your strategy is valid. What's going wrong here, is that `Path` is a path to a directory, not a file. `SubFold` then are only *directories* as they are found on the `Path`. `fullfile(Path, SubFold(k).name)` finally creates a path to a subdirectory of `Path`. A subdirectory is not a file, thus `fopen` will tell you that it's an incorrect filename.

You'll probably need another `dir()` call, e.g. `dir(F)` to get all *files* on the path specified by `F`.